# XCode9 how to get right click > Structure > Reindent back?

Tags: code-formatting, editing, xcode9

I see that XCode9 is messing up the indentation of my code. Before this could be fixed with right click > structure > re-indent. How do I get equivalent behavior in XCode9?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This **won't** get the Structure->Re-Indent context menu back but *might* be useful.

There's a `^I`  (`ctrl + i`) shortcut for that, which re-indents selection.

If you don't want to use Key Bindings, the command is available using the menu:

```
Editor->Structure->Re-Indent
```

**Note** that default combination looks very much alike `^|` (`ctrl + shift + \`) on Key Binding pane . I've been banging this combo for some time and even redefined the shortcut to `ctrl+shift+\` before figuring out the correct one:
[image]

Comment: I've been using Mac for 6 years and still don't know what those crazy symbols they use for options, alt, etc. I just used that menu to change it to Shift+R

Comment: In Xcode 9, you can finally use Tab and Shift+Tab to indent multiple lines of code.